# Does the Im function work with symbolic arguments?

Tags: symbolic, simplifying-expressions, assumptions, complex

Does the `Im` function work with symbolic arguments?

```
Clear[ y, t, k, ω ]

A ( Cos[ k y ] + I Sin[ k y ] ) 2I Sin[ ω t ] //ComplexExpand

(* Output: 2 I A Cos[ k y] Sin[ t ω ] - 2 A Sin[ k y ] Sin[ t ω ] *)

Im[ % ]

(* Output: -2 Im[ A Sin[ k y ] Sin[ t ω ] ] + 2 Re[ A Cos[ k y ] Sin[ t ω ] ] *)
```

Expected output: `-2 A Sin[ k y ] Sin[ t ω ]`

Comment: You could apply `ComplexExpand` to the last output again, e.g. `ComplexExpand[Im[%]]` instead of `Im[%]`

Comment: I'm amazed by all the good answers, but still a little puzzled. One says that ComplexExpand is not needed, the other that TargetFunctions is not needed. Both lead to succinct expressions that give the correct answer. What is it that makes one or the other, or neither, preferable?

Comment: @Artes, Sorry for not responding. I'm not very good at forum protocols, as I don't use them very often, each is a little different, and I find the locations of the buttons a little confusing. I think I forgot to set automatic email for this one. Even now, I am not sure that I have satisfied the request. I'm happy with the answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should assume that your variables are real, (if you want M to proceed further) because Mathematica treats variables in general as complex. One of many ways to do it :

```
 expr = A ((Cos[k y] + I Sin[k y]) 2 I Sin[t ω]); 
 Refine[ Im[ expr], (A | k y | t ω) ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> 2 A Cos[k y] Sin[t ω]
> ```

We needn't use `ComplexExpand` defining `expr`, but in this case it is the simplest approach (pointed out by Heike) :

```
ComplexExpand @ Im @ expr
```

Some other ways of imposing assumptions :

```
Assuming[(A | k y | t ω) ∈ Reals, Refine[ Im[ expr] ] ]
```

another way yielding the same result :

```
Block[{$Assumptions = A ∈ Reals && k y ∈ Reals && t ω ∈ Reals},
       Refine @ Im[ expr] ]
```

> ```
>  2 A Cos[k y] Sin[t ω]
> ```

Comment: `ComplexExpand[]` actually works nicely here: `ComplexExpand[Im[A ((Cos[k y] + I Sin[k y])*2 I Sin[ω t])], TargetFunctions -> Im]`; unfortunately the `TargetFunctions` option is not as well-known as I think it should be.

Comment: Note that, in place of the assumption like `A ∈ Reals` you can use the assumption `_Symbol ∈ Reals` to assume that *all* explicit variables are real.  This allows you to encapsulate this in a function without having to manually pass a list of arguments. For an exhaustive discussion, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156648/1806).