# How can I specify a numerical order for variables?

Tags: syntax

I need to specify that a variable is less than another, and greater than yet another, in a Mathematica program, because I will later apply a test to them that will determine what functional form to use. I also need `Sign[]` to give the correct answer. I tried using `TagSet` like this:

```
h /: (h>=d0) = True
h /: (h<=d1) = True
```

but this does not work with `Sign[h-d0]`, for example, and

```
h /: Sign[h - d0] = 1;
```

fails because it says *h* is too deep.

An example of how I will use this:

```
f[x_] := Exp[ c Sign[h-x] ]
```

where `x` can take the values `d0` or `d1`. (This will be used to set up boundary relations to solve for a set of coefficients to solve a PDE.) I suppose I could use some `If` statements to set the whole thing up, but thought it would be nicer to have a specification of the properties of `h`.

I'm sure this should be easy to do - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could just rescale $x$ to $\xi =x/h$, so you can work on ${\mathrm{sgn}}(1-\xi)$.

Comment: is it for numeric or analytic solution of PDE?

Comment: Unprotect[Sign]; Sign[h - d0] = 1;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refine with assumptions might be useful. Quick example:

```
In[2]:= $Assumptions = x < y < z;

In[3]:= Refine[{Sign[x - y], Sign[z - x]}]

Out[3]= {-1, 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, that's what I had in mind. I want the variable to acquire the property, so I can rely on it being evaluated properly in different contexts (`If[h > d0, ...]`, or `Sign[h-d0]`, etc). What I'm doing is having Mathematica solve a set of equations that are set up for a layered medium, where the behavior of some functions depends on whether the layer is above or below the source. I'll vote you up when I get the points!

Comment: @TomDickens Sometimes it is better to use assumptions locally, e.g. `Refine[{Sign[x - y], Sign[z - x]}, Assumptions -> x < y < z]`. You might find useful answers to these questions : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/does-the-im-function-work-with-symbolic-arguments

Comment: @TomDickens Pay attention to the difference between the second argument between `Refine[expr,Assumptions ->assum]`, and  `Refine[expr, assum]` e.g. see the documentatio of `Refine`.

Comment: @Artes - Thanks for the valuable comments. My code is working now! Tom